# Aggregating rows with same id number and inputting column value based on aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

```
df = pandas.DataFrame( { 
    "ID" : ["1123", "2325", "9788", "1123", "9788" , "5421"] , 
    "Type" : ["Red", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Red", "Black"] } )
```

The df should look like this - note that ID number 1123 and 9788 have both Black and Red 'Type'

```
     ID     Type
0   1123     Red
1   2323    Black
2   9788    Black
3   1123    Black
4   9788     Red
5   5421    Black
```

I would like to write some code that aggregates rows. If the ID number has both Black and Red 'Type' I would like it to read Red otherwise Black as is shown below.

```
     ID     Type
0   1123    Red
1   2323    Black
2   9788    Red
3   5421    Black
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `groupby` and take `max` value (since 'Red' > 'Black'):

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Type'].max()
```

Output:

```
     ID   Type
0  1123  Red  
1  2325  Black
2  5421  Black
3  9788  Red
```

**Update:** If you have more types, you can convert to ordered categorical, specifying the required order, and then use `groupby` and `max` in exactly the same way:

```
df['Type'] = pd.Categorical(df['Type'],
                            categories=['Black', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Red'],
                            ordered=True)

df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Type'].max()
```

Here we'll have 'Black' < 'Green' < 'Blue' < 'Red'

Comment: Okay fair - In reality I have 5 different 'type' and the one I want chosen is not discernible alphabetically

Comment: it looks like the groupby did not work - there are still multiple rows of the same ID

Comment: Hm, it certainly works fine with the data sample that you provided... Could it be that IDs may have some characters that we don't see, like trailing/leading spaces/tabs or something like that?

Comment: If that's the case, try with `df.groupby(df['ID'].str.strip())['Type'].max()`, `.str.strip` should remove all those characters

Comment: This worked nicely. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Sort the type by order, and drop_duplicates by "ID", keep the type you wanted.

```
df['order_tag'] = df['Type'].map({'Red':1,'Black':2})
df.sort_values('order_tag').drop_duplicates('ID', keep='first').sort_index()
```

output:

```
     ID   Type  order_tag
0  1123    Red          1
1  2325  Black          2
4  9788    Red          1
5  5421  Black          2
```